# loop through attributes in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I made a menu with custom block in wordpress gutenberg and made it editable using RichText component but every time I try to edit those, changes will apply to all of them, instead I want individual texts.
I know it can be done by looping through objects but I don't know how

Sidebar block:

```
import { RichText } from "@wordpress/block-editor"
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks"

registerBlockType("ourblocktheme/sidebarmenucontent", {
  attributes: {
    text: {type: 'string'},
    size: {type: 'string'}
  },
  title: "Sidebar Menu Content",
  edit: EditComponent,
  save: SaveComponent
})

function EditComponent(props) {
  function textHandler(x) {
    props.setAttributes({ text: x })
  }

  return (
    <>
    <ul className="main-menu">
        <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav="0" href="#home">
                <span className="m-icon">
                    <i className="bi-house-door"></i>
                </span>
                 <RichText value={props.attributes.text} onChange={textHandler} />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav="1" href="#services">
                <span className="m-icon">
                    <i className="bi-person"></i>
                </span>
                <RichText value={props.attributes.text} onChange={textHandler} />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav="2" href="#services">
                <span className="m-icon">
                    <i className="bi-briefcase"></i>
                </span>
                <RichText value={props.attributes.text} onChange={textHandler} />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav="3" href="#work">
                <span className="m-icon">
                    <i className="bi-columns"></i>
                </span>
                <RichText value={props.attributes.text} onChange={textHandler} />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav="4" href="#contactus">
                <span className="m-icon">
                    <i className="bi-telephone"></i>
                </span>
                <RichText value={props.attributes.text} onChange={textHandler} />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </>
  )
}

function SaveComponent() {
  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  )
}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your block attributes, an array of strings is needed to enable storing multiple text strings for your menu items. Looking at the structure of `<ul><li><a><span><i>..</i></a></li><ul>`, an attribute [query can extract the values](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query-source) from the markup into a useful array, eg:

```js
attributes: {
    menuItems: {
        type: 'array', 
        source: 'query',    // Searches the markup
        selector: 'li',     // for each <li> element
        query: {
            text: {
                type: 'string',
                selector: 'span.label', // then find this selector
                source: 'text'          // get value of text
            },
            href: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute',  // and this attributes
                selector: 'a[href]'   // value of link href 
            },
            className: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute', // and this attributes
                selector: 'i[class]' // value of class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An additional `<span className="label">{text}</span>` inside `<a>...</a>` is required to make the query work as expected. If we queried the text of `<a>` as in the current markup, it would include all the `<span><i>...</i></span>` content as part of the string (which *shouldn't be edited* as part of the `<RichText>` component).

The resulting array structure can then be used as the `"default": []` value for the `menuItems` attribute:

```
[
    {
        text: 'Home',
        href: '#home',
        className: 'bi-house-door'
    },
    {
        text: 'Services',
        href: '#services',
        className: 'bi-person'
    },
    ... // etc..
]
```

The next step as anticipated, is to do a "loop" in `edit()` to change each text value independently. I prefer [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax) rather than a loop as I find more compact/cleaner and includes a useful index, eg:

**edit()**

```js
function EditComponent({attributes, setAttributes}) {
    const { menuItems } = attributes;

    // TODO: Add updateMenuItem function defintion here..

    return (
        <ul className="main-menu">
            {menuItems && menuItems.map(({ text, href, className }, index) => {
                // If there are menuItems, map them out
                return (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <a href={href}>
                            <span className="m-icon">
                                <i className={className}></i>
                            </span>
                            <RichText
                                value={text}
                                tagName="span" // tagName and className needed for query
                                className="label" onChange={} // TODO: Call updateMenuItem() onChange
                            />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, `setAttributes()` doesn't work for an array of objects, so a helper function is required to avoid mutations on an existing object, eg:

```js
...
function updateMenuItem(text, href, className, index) {
    const updatedMenuItems = [...menuItems]; // Copy of existing menuItems array

    updatedMenuItems[index] = { text: text, href: href, className: className }; // Update the targeted index with new values

    setAttributes({ menuItems: updatedMenuItems }); // Update menuItems with the new array
}
...
<RichText
    ... 
    onChange={(text) => updateMenuItem(text, href, className, index)}
/>
...
```

The final step is to ensure the content is saved to markup correctly by using the same map technique as in `edit()` - with a minor change to `<RichText.Content>` needed:

**save()**

```js
function SaveComponent({attributes}) {
 const { menuItems } = attributes;
    
    return (
        <ul>
            {menuItems && menuItems.map(({ text, href, className }, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <a data-scroll-nav={index} href={href}>
                            <span className="m-icon">
                                <i className={className}></i>
                            </span>
                            <RichText.Content tagName="span" className="label" value={text} />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

If you have reached this far, hopefully you have a working, editable example based on your menu. As with everything, there are many ways to do something and while the above "works", I would suggest more block-like approach in general:

If you break your menu down, it is multiple links styled as buttons. The `[core/button]` blocks is very close to that, as is `[core/list]`, so I would either extend those blocks, restyle them or make your own that is just the "menu item" link/button content. I would create a parent "menu" block and use [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/) to be able to add and edit as many "menu items" as you need, this would eliminate the need for query attribute and looping plus you could easily reorder them.

I find it helpful to reflect on a issue/solution, consider why it works/was challenging and then find an easier way...